Random Binary Matrix Column Space with XOR Addition in Regards to Random Binary Vector
Given that you have a random binary matrix $A$, which is has dimensions $(n,l)$ where $n>l$ (has more rows than columns), is it possible that a random binary vector $\vec{b}$ is in the column space of $A$ when addition is defined as the XOR operator?
When given the equation $$A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$$ we can calculate the $b_1$ (the first value of $\vec{b}$) as $$a_{1,1}x_{1} \oplus a_{1,2}x_{2} \oplus ... \oplus a_{1,l}x_{l} = b_1$$
where $\oplus$ is defined as the XOR operator.
This process can be done to calculate all values in $\vec{b}$.
The values of $A$, $\vec{x}$, $\vec{b}$ are all binary (aka 0 or 1).
I understand that in normal circumstances since matrix $A$ is overdetermined the chance that a random vector $\vec{b}$ is in the column space of $A$ is very low, but since $A$, $\vec{x}$, $\vec{b}$ are all binary I am hoping that $\vec{b}$ will always (or with high probability) be in the column space. Is this possible? If not what properties would $A$ need to have to make this true?

Considering $A$ as a matrix over (the field) $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the maximum dimension of the column space is $l$ (this maximum occurs if the columns are linearly independent). But this means the maximum possible number of vectors in the column space is $2^l$. So the maximum possible probability (depending on the random matrix $A$) that a random binary vector of length $n$ is in the column space is $\frac{2^l}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2^{n-l}}$. Since $n>l$, the most this probability could be is $\frac12$; and lower if $n$ is more than $1$ greater than $l$.
So, for instance, if $n = 7$ and $l=3$, the maximum possible probability that a random binary vector of length $7$ is in the column space is at most $\frac{1}{16}$. And the probability is lower if the columns are not linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Thank you for the response! What if we make it so that the amount of columns is greater than rows? In that case we would have an under determined system hence the vectors in the column space should have infinite solutions.

@CLox Not if you're working over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in which case there are only $2^k$ vectors of length $k$ for any positive integer $k$.
